# Sequential writing and reading (two threads)

Tags: java, beginner, multithreading, thread-safety

I am new to Java.
My task is to create a `SequentalWriter` class and a `SequentalReader` class that implement the *Runnable* interface. They must provide a sequence of write-read operations (i.e., write-read-write-read-write-read, etc.).

**The task assumes only the use of "synchronized", "notify" and "wait".**

I would like to know if something needs to be changed or I have any unknown bugs?

```
import java.lang.Thread;
import vectors.Array; /* My array implementation */
import vectors.CircularLinkedList; /* My list implementation */
import vectors.IVector; /* The interface that Array and CircularLinkedList implement */

public class Task7Part2 {
    volatile int a = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IVector arr1 = new Array(2);
        System.out.print("[Test] arr1: "); arr1.print();
        Keeper keeperArr1 = new Keeper(arr1);
        SequentalWriter seqWriter = new SequentalWriter(keeperArr1);
        SequentalReader seqReader = new SequentalReader(keeperArr1);
        (new Thread(seqWriter)).start();
        (new Thread(seqReader)).start();

        // Sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        IVector arr2 = new Array(3);
        System.out.print("[Test] arr2: "); arr2.print();
        Keeper keeperArr2 = new Keeper(arr2);
        seqWriter = new SequentalWriter(keeperArr2);
        seqReader = new SequentalReader(keeperArr2);
        (new Thread(seqWriter)).start();
        (new Thread(seqReader)).start();

        // Sleep
        try {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        IVector list = new CircularLinkedList(4);
        System.out.print("[Test] list: "); list.print();
        Keeper keeperList = new Keeper(list);
        seqWriter = new SequentalWriter(keeperList);
        seqReader = new SequentalReader(keeperList);
        (new Thread(seqWriter)).start();
        (new Thread(seqReader)).start();
    }

    public static class Keeper {
        public volatile IVector vector;
        public volatile boolean isWrite;

        public Keeper(IVector vector) {
            this.vector = vector;
            this.isWrite = true;
        }
    }

    public static class SequentalWriter implements Runnable {
        public SequentalWriter(Keeper keeper) {
            this.keeper = keeper;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0, size = keeper.vector.size(); i < size; ++i) {
                    double d = Math.random();
                    synchronized(keeper) {
                        while (!keeper.isWrite) {
                            keeper.wait();
                        }
                        keeper.vector.set(i, d);
                        System.out.println("Write: " + d + " to position " + i);
                        keeper.isWrite = false;
                        keeper.notify();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        private Keeper keeper;
    }

    public static class SequentalReader implements Runnable {
        public SequentalReader(Keeper keeper) {
            this.keeper = keeper;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                for (int i = 0, size = keeper.vector.size(); i < size; ++i) {
                    synchronized(keeper) {
                        while (keeper.isWrite) {
                            keeper.wait();
                        }
                        System.out.println("Read: " + keeper.vector.get(i) + " from position " + i);
                        keeper.isWrite = true;
                        keeper.notify();
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
        }
        private Keeper keeper;
    }
}
```

Expected behavior:

```
[Test] arr1: 0.0 0.0
Write: 0.11832270210075957 to position 0
Read: 0.11832270210075957 from position 0
Write: 0.18019604451043925 to position 1
Read: 0.18019604451043925 from position 1
[Test] arr2: 0.0 0.0 0.0
Write: 0.9208224707735939 to position 0
Read: 0.9208224707735939 from position 0
Write: 0.5204299894796229 to position 1
Read: 0.5204299894796229 from position 1
Write: 0.6221915557485913 to position 2
Read: 0.6221915557485913 from position 2
[Test] list: 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
Write: 0.2718292615666258 to position 0
Read: 0.2718292615666258 from position 0
Write: 0.5589338156490498 to position 1
Read: 0.5589338156490498 from position 1
Write: 0.11919746734454817 to position 2
Read: 0.11919746734454817 from position 2
Write: 0.7266106446478366 to position 3
Read: 0.7266106446478366 from position 3
```

Comment: Is vectors the name of your pacage?